# oracle sql date not later than today

Tags: sql, oracle, logic

I need to display some data if it's a
   - new data
   - updated data
let's say, I will be basing these data from a publishdate column and updated column where publishdate and updateddate are both timestamps ? . so how to compute the date if it's a new one ?

Comment: i have a publishdate column, and I want to display the data that are published within this day, and not those were posted yesterday nor earlier

Answer (score 76, accepted):

For last 24 hours:

```
Where publish_date >= sysdate -1
```

or anytime today (midnight forward)

```
where publish_date >= trunc(sysdate)
```

If this is a big table, I assume you have an index on publish_date.  If you use trunc(publish_date), it may not be able to use the index (untested, but run an explain plan to be sure).

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
Where TRUNC(sysdate) = TRUNC(publish_date)
```

`sysdate` returns today's date with the time. The `TRUNC` removes the time part

Comment: I don't want to spoil a -1, but as @tbone explained, using `TRUNC(publish_date)` is probably a bad idea and an performance killer in this situation